# Automorphism on Symmetric Group and Transpositions

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

I've been looking into the group of automorphisms of the symmetric group $S_{n}$ for when $n > 6$.  Something which is claimed frequently is that if an automorphism sends a transposition to a transposition, then it has to be an inner automorphism (and is hence used to show that Aut($S_{n}$) = $S_{n}$.

However, for $n > 6$, is there a way to constructively show that any automorphism sends a transposition to a transposition?

I've been attempting to show it using centralizers but haven't had much luck.

Thanks!

Comment: For a proof of the first statement see here: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Transposition-preserving_automorphism_of_symmetric_group_is_inner.

Comment: It's just combinatorics. You have to show that the number $n(n-1)/2$ of transpositions is less than the size of any other conjugacy class of elements of order $2$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I understand that proof, but I was trying to understand where the fact that we are getting that these automorphisms sends transpositions to transpositions comes from.  And is there a way to do the proof without combinatorics and conjugacy classes but show it directly?

Comment: I think, no. How would you "constructively show" that any automorphism sends transpositions to transpositions ? You can only "construct" automorphisms which do this, but that is something else.

Comment: I meant supposing that an automorphism didn't send a transposition to a transposition and then deriving some sort of contradiction directly from that, rather than using a counting argument.